# custom check box browser cross compatible

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a custom check box, that should be fine across all browsers, however I am having problems with IE, EDGE and FireFox

**FireFox, Edge and IE**

1. Problem is the tick is black and square check box

Dose anyone know why, as I thought this code was cross browser compatible.

```css
.regular-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 18px;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  border-radius: 18px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white !important;
}
.regular-checkbox {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.regular-checkbox:checked:after {
  content: '\2714';
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  font-size: 37px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' class='regular-checkbox' checked />
```

Comment: _“as I thought this code was cross browser compatible”_ – well, it’s not. Many browsers allow very little formatting on form elements - and even asking for rounded borders might be too much already. That’s why most custom checkbox solutions only hide the original checkbox element, instead of trying to format it - the formatting is then applied to other elements. And ::before/::after pseudo elements are supposed to be rendered as if any actual child element was inserted - but `input` can not have child elements, so using generated content on such elements might not work in all browsers either.

Comment: I understand that, that is  why I am hiding the standard check on browsers "appearance: none;"

Comment: That does not hide the element, it only prevents the browser from making it look like its "default" checkboxes. But that has little to do with the issues I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not cross browser compatible. -webkit-appearance and -moz-appearance are not standard and should not be used, also they behave differently in different browsers.

My suggestion is to use combination of input and label, where you will hide checkbox input and use background images for checkbox. Also be sure not to hide input with display:none because of accessibility.

Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms